# How can I mathematically proof an incoherent superposition of waves?

Tags: signal-processing, harmonic-functions

Let $\psi = A(t)\cos(\theta_1(t))$ and $\phi = B(t)\cos(\theta_2(t))$ two independent waves which phases and amplitudes depend on the time. Then it follows that the intensity of the superposition of these waves is,

$$I \propto  (\psi + \phi)^2 
= A^2(t)\cos^2(\theta_1(t)) + B^2(t)\cos^2(\theta_2(t)) \\ + 2A(t)B(t)\cos(\theta_1(t))\cos(\theta_2(t)) $$

However, when it comes about taking average over time, for the case of an incoherent superposition, the cross term is zero, so

$$\lim \limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} A(t)B(t)\cos(\theta_1(t))\cos(\theta_2(t)) = 0$$

$$\lim \limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} A^2(t)\cos^2(\theta_1(t)) = \frac{1}{2}\langle A^2(t) \rangle $$

$$\lim \limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T}  B^2(t)\cos^2(\theta_2(t)) = \frac{1}{2}\langle B^2(t) \rangle $$
and
$$I =\frac{1}{2}\langle A^2(t) \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle B^2(t) \rangle = I_{\psi} + I_{\phi}$$

How can I mathematically proof these integrals?

NOTE: My aim is to represent an incoherent addition of waves (e.g two light beams partially polarized). If there is any consideration or assumption that I am missing, please, let me know.

Comment: What do you know about $A(t)$ and $B(t)$? (If they are totally arbitrary functions, you have no chance).

Comment: For the case of signal processing, there is always assumed that amplitudes and phases may vary on time.

Comment: ...so non-constant. You still have no chance ; you need to assume more properties. Are they periodic functions for instance?